# About signal filter and composition

Tags: python, filter, scipy, signals

I have got three signals, acc_x, acc_y, acc_z. I need to compose them in order to compute the magnitude of the acc. I would like to ask the following question:

what is better opt1 or opt2? or opt3?:

**opt1**: first apply a filter (sp.signal.savgol_filter) to reduce the noise to each single signal and then compute the magnitude or,

**opt2**: first compute the magnitude and then apply a filter (sp.signal.savgol_filter) to the composed to reduce the noise?

**opt3**: Any other good suggestion? 
Any of your suggestion would be very appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Best Regards, Carlo

Comment: [dsp.stackexchange.com](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) is probably a better site for this question.

Comment: Yes it is. I have got it there https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/48912/about-filtering-and-composing-signals but no answer.